# How should we handle numerous tags referring to Eastern Orthodoxy?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I have noticed that the definitions and usage of the [eastern-orthodox](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eastern-orthodox) and [orthodox](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthodox) tags are identical. I also noticed that [greek-orthodox](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek-orthodox) is a separate tag, yet this is also Eastern Orthodox (it is not a separate 'denomination' as in Protestantism, it is the same Church under a different jurisdiction. It would be more akin to having a separate tag for different dioceses of the Roman Catholic Church, which in my opinion makes no sense). All of the posts currently tagged [orthodox](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthodox) are related to Eastern Orthodoxy. How should this redundancy be resolved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I propose establishing [orthodox](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthodox) as a synonym for [eastern-orthodox](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eastern-orthodox), which can be voted for (or against) [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tags/eastern-orthodox/synonyms).

I would propose removing the [greek-orthodox](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek-orthodox) tag and placing the four (4) posts tagged this way under the [eastern-orthodox](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eastern-orthodox) tag. Otherwise this opens up the possibility of separate tags for every national jurisdiction of Eastern Orthodoxy (one for every eastern European nation).

Comment: I tried, but in addition to the 1250 rep, you also have to have 5 upvotes on the tag. Sheesh!

Comment: @AffableGeek that's crazy, looks like someone approved it though. Thanks for trying!

Comment: I've removed the [tag:greek-orthodox] tag from the four (4) posts that had it, they were all tagged [tag:eastern-orthodox] already. Just waiting for someone to delete the [tag:greek-orthodox] tag who has authority to do so.

Comment: @DanO'Day. If a tag exists on no posts, it will soon disappear naturally, with no need for moderator intervention.

Answer (score 0):

We could delete the [orthodox](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthodox) and the [greek-orthodox](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek-orthodox) tags and only have an [eastern-orthodox](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eastern-orthodox) tag for simplicity. This is not my preferred solution but I wanted to have it as an option here.